# Why does blender cover the whole cube and not selected areas with materials?

Tags: materials

I have tried a lot of different ways to cover the Roof of my cube with a material, but every time I tried, blender covers the whole cube with the painting color. How can I simply coloring just parts of a cube?

Answer (score 4):

To add a material to a specifc face (you can only assign *and* see material colors to faces), you first need to add a base material to your object, next enter *Edit* mode, select the face and then add a new material slot and create a new material or pick an already created one from the list and press *Assign*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select the desired faces and assign the material using 'assign' button in *material panel*.

[image]